# Is there a Helm chart for installing Tekton pipelines?

Tags: tekton

I'm using Tekton (https://tekton.dev/) to run CI/CD pipelines on top of Kubernetes and I'd like to deploy multiple pipelines one for each environment eg. DEV/UAT/PREPROD/PROD, has anyone seen a helm chart to deploy pipelines?

I have tried deploying the necessary Kubernetes objects using `kubectl apply` for my DEV pipeline but when going to deploy UAT/PREPROD/PROD pipelines there's far too much duplicated code. So I would like to use Helm package manager to have a single pipeline template and deploy my pipelines using that template via a `helm install` command.

Side note: I have to use Tekton as the CI/CD tool to satisfy pipeline deployment requirements; cloud-agnostic, run pipelines locally in Kind and running each pipeline stage with least-privileged security by assuming IAM roles in AWS.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

There is no official charts deploying Tekton. Arguably, helm wouldn't be much useful here: there are very few things you may configure, and their defaults should suit most installations.

Tekton is composed of several components. Each with its own GitHub repository. Installation manifests are pushed as release assets: all you need is to apply those, to deploy the corresponding component.

The main component is Tekton Pipelines (comes with Pipelines/PipelineRuns, Tasks/TaskRuns, deprecated PipelineResources), https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/releases
Tekton Pipelines is the ONLY one you must install. The remaining ones discussed below are optional.

Next, we have Tekton Triggers (comes with EventListeners, TriggerBinding, or TriggerTemplates), https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/releases

The Tekton Dashboard has its own project as well, https://github.com/tektoncd/dashboard/releases

More recently, there's also Tekton Chains, something about supply chain security, https://github.com/tektoncd/chains/releases

As well as Tekton Results, https://github.com/tektoncd/results/releases

Most of which might be installed and lifecycled using the Tekton Operator, https://github.com/tektoncd/operator/blob/main/docs/install.md (again, no Helm chart: just a plain release file). Mote: running OpenShift and derivatives, you may install the openshift-pipelines operator from OLM.

You may not need all those components to start up. Depends what you mean to build on top of Tekton. Picking which of those components you want to install  is pretty much all the customization you need to go through, installing Tekton.

Comment: my bad. I delete my answer for OpenShift as it is indeed irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

There's now a Helm chart available with examples on how you can deploy multiple pipelines in a single command here https://github.com/cogitogroupltd/tekton-helm-chart-examples

Answer (score 0):

not sure, if I understand the question correct: I was searching for a way to put tekton-tasks and pipelines unter source-control (git). For me there is no other way to enable clean staging.
Finally I gave it a try simply to deploy tasks and pipelines with helm. Within templates I created

`task.yaml`

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: hello-from-helm
spec:
  steps:
    - name: echo
      image: alpine
      script: |
        #!/bin/sh
        echo "Hello helm"
```

and `pipeline.yaml`

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: new-pipeline
spec:
  params: []
  resources: []
  workspaces: []
  tasks:
    - name: hello-from-helm
      taskRef:
        kind: Task
        name: hello-from-helm
      params: []
  finally: []
```

after `helm install tekton-stuff .` at least on my openshift I can run the pipelines as tehy would have been created "manually".